# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only the target location may be specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

I'm writing my first spring boot application. on running the following command i'm getting the exception.

```
spring init --build maven --groupId com.redhat.examples\ --version 1.0 --java-version 1.8 --dependencies web\ --name hola-springboot hola-springboot
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only the target location may be specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.init.InitCommand$InitOptionHandler.createProjectGenerationRequest(InitCommand.java:218)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.init.InitCommand$InitOptionHandler.generateProject(InitCommand.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.init.InitCommand$InitOptionHandler.run(InitCommand.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
```

Comment: I was able to run it successfully on windows by removing the '\'s in your command and running using the spring-cli version 1.4.1

Comment: D:\Data>spring init --build maven --groupId com.redhat.examples --version 1.0 --java-version 1.8 --dependencies web --
me hola-springboot hola-springboot
Using service at https://start.spring.io
Project extracted to 'D:\Data\hola-springboot'

Comment: Yup, after removing '\' it worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to run it successfully on windows by removing the `'\'s` in your command and running using the spring-cli version 1.4.1

`spring init --build maven --groupId com.redhat.examples --version 1.0 --java-version 1.8 --dependencies web -- me hola-springboot hola-springboot Using service at start.spring.io Project extracted to '\Data\hola-springboot'`

Answer (score 0):

This error Comes When there is any Whitespace or Invalid character in command.Remove Whitespace or invalid character from command